# How to change the size of the components list in Nsis?

Tags: installation, nsis

I have developed an installer with Nsis with a components page in which the user can select the components to install. I would like to change the size of the component list window and make it greater in order to make visible the entire text of each component without scroll bars.
Does anybody know how I can do it? I'm using simple MUI.nsh, not MUI2.nsh.
Any help will be pleasant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nsis custom page sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530372/nsis-custom-page-sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_SMALLDESC or MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_NODESC, if that is not enough you will need to use a custom dialog (`ChangeUI`)